# System.ArgumentException: "Parameter is not Valid" Memorystream to Image

Tags: c#, image, memorystream

I have checked other StackOverflow Questions but none seem to help, as most of them work with a "base64string" this wont help me cause my byte[] is encoded with Windows-1252.

**My Problem:**

I'm using a Barcode Scanner to make a Picture, I use `Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252").GetString(e.Buffer))`. e is the `DataaReceivedEventArgs` and it gives me a bytearray.

I have to convert it to a string because I have to cut some parts out of the response this step has to stay.

I then use `Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252").GetBytes(response)` to convert it to a ByteArray.

I then just make a `MemoryStream` and use it in `Image.FromStream(ms)`. The Problem is it *WORKS* the first time without any problems. But after the Second time it gives me the Invalid Parameter Exception.

```
  byte[] bBytes = await responseZuBytesArray();

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bBytes))
            {
                pcbBildAnzeige.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                pcbBildAnzeige.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
            }

            tIsStarted = false;
```

i have tried setting the Position of the MemoryStream, tried to convert it to a Bitmap first. i have tried so much but i think there is something simple im just not seeing thats why im asking here

Comment: Note the [gray blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Character_set).  That means you can't store an image in a string.  You really must use base64.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the byte array using class `System.Drawing.ImageConverter`;

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)new System.Drawing.ImageConverter().ConvertFrom(bBytes);
```